# upgrade to django 1.11.12 error in models/manager.py contribute_to_class

Tags: python, django

I haven't touched a project in a long time and realized I upgraded my django to version 1.11.12.  Trying to re-run project (runserver) and found several out of date packages (easy-thumbnails and psycopg2).  Ran pip install upgrade on those.  Now when I run, I get the following error and it seems like it is coming form my models?   Not sure what it is telling me though or the proper course of action. Maybe there was another upgrade step I missed when I upgraded to django 1.11? (sorry been ages since I touched this code)

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x104ab2500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/shane.thomas/programming/sw_nga_site/swsite/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/fields/image.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..models import Image
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .clipboardmodels import *  # flake8: noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/models/clipboardmodels.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import filemodels
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/models/filemodels.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .foldermodels import Folder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/models/foldermodels.py", line 240, in <module>
    mptt.register(Folder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/__init__.py", line 12, in register
    from mptt.models import MPTTModelBase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/models.py", line 379, in <module>
    class MPTTModel(six.with_metaclass(MPTTModelBase, models.Model)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 808, in __new__
    return meta(name, bases, d)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/models.py", line 262, in __new__
    cls = super_new(meta, class_name, bases, class_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 162, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/managers.py", line 81, in contribute_to_class
    super(TreeManager, self).contribute_to_class(model, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 120, in contribute_to_class
    setattr(model, name, ManagerDescriptor(self))
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Looks like you need to update your version of MPTT; you should probably update the other dependencies as well.

Comment: good call, doing pip install -U django-mptt fixed it, then got a filer error.  Upgraded that still getting file error so digging deeper. I thought there was a way to say 'upgrade everything in my project' somehow.  Been to long since I touched this stuff :(

Comment: Looks like django-filer does not work under django 1.10 or greater :/

Comment: Side note you’ve probably already heard: You would be better off using a virtual environment for each project to avoid these surprises. With a VE in place you can upgrade on your own schedule.

Comment: Or downgrade if there is an issue?    I am guessing that is the virtualenv?   I should of set things up that way, actually going back through the code I could tell I learned a lot more than when I first started this project too.  I am curious though.  With a VE how does it prevent these surprises?   I get the gist but don't understand how I wouldnt just have the same issues in that environment?  Not needing a long response here, I guess it is a good topic to google and its been a while since I have dove into django so probably time to.